# Partial input verification

Tags: c++, error-checking

I'm trying to implement input verification in my code.
I'm using `.ignore()`, as well as `.clear()`.
The input is rejected as it should be when there is anything else than a number in the forefront of the input, but if i.e. the input is "12d".
The program does not recognize this as a inherent mistake (although in theory it should).

How can I go about fixing this issue?

```
cin >> temp;
if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),13);
    cout << "Wrong input format, try again: ";
}
else if (!cin.fail())
{
    break;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The indents are incorrect.

Comment: In theory it shouldn't - extracting an integer stops at a non-digit and succeeds. If you want some other behaviour, you need to handle that yourself, for instance by looking ahead in the stream.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job. If you goal is to input a line of text, this is what `std::getline` is for. That it's job. It's not the job of the `>>` formatted conversion operator to read a line of text. Trying to shoehorn the task of doing that on the operator, and then fiddling with the input stream state, trying to get it right, is just making trouble for yourself. Use the right tool for the right job. Read a line of text using `std::getline`, then take it apart and see if this is what you wanted.

Comment: What are you `break`ing here??

Answer (score 0):

This code verifies the input. It can be modified to retrieve the number by first taking the input into a `std::string` using `getline` and then looping through its contents. If input format is correct then create a `stringstream` having the string and use `>>` operator on it to get the value.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    char ch;
    bool flag1 = true; // true if a non-digit, non-space character is not encountered yet
    bool flag2 = false; // stores if a digit has been encountered
    while(std::cin.get(ch) and flag1)
        if(not isspace(ch))
            if(isdigit(ch))
                flag2 = true;
            else
                flag1 = false;
    std::cout << "Input format is " << ((flag1 and flag2) ? "" : "not ") << "correct!";
    return 0;
}
```